# How to patch CMake generated Visual Studio project files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

Is there any way in CMake how to call a command that changes the generated .vcxproj files?
I want to patch some things within the auto generated files.
The problem is !when! to call such a tool within the cmake generation process.

Comment: What exactly do you need to patch? What are you trying to achieve? While in theory patching the generated files might be doable, I would strongly advise against it. Your build system would quickly turn into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I want to move the entries of ClCompile/AdditionalIncludeDirectories to PropertyGroup/IncludePath. I need that because VAssist uses the latter for optimization purposes and CMAke does not support that directly.

Comment: Additional use case is for adding additional projects to solution for project types not supported by CMake (i.e. Python).